# Routing a symfony service and use data in javascript to make charts

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, chart.js

I want to make some charts for my back office

I have my symfony back-end and the chart.js library to make my charts

I'm new and i wanted to know if what i wanted to do is possible

I have my service, we will call him stats. I have a method in this service returing a php array

I want to make a route to request this method and get the array

I will get from this url response in my views for my back office and make a chart from it

Is it possible ? Is it the good way to do it ?

Comment: yes, is possibile, you can simply expose a route with a controller that call the service and return a JsonResponse with the result of the service invocation. The service need some input parameters in order to work? Pass it as query string

Comment: ok i will try it @Matteo thank you

Comment: Hi, you can post some code here if you need more help